# O que são mensagens semânticas no Git?

Tags: git, semântica

Eventualmente, quando navego por alguns dos repositórios do GitHub, deparo-me com certas mensagens de *commit* padronizadas:

> feat(*): initiate re-write

Ou:

> refactor(*): remove unwanted files

O que são essas palavras (`feat`, `refactor`...) que precedem a mensagem em si?
Existem outras, mas só citei duas delas.

---

Com uma breve pesquisa, consegui concluir que são mensagens de *commit* semânticas. Mas quais são as regras para usá-las? E como usá-las da maneira correta?

Comment: Não há uma regra de como e onde deve usar. O ideal é utilizar um padrão em todo o projeto, mas isso varia de pessoa para pessoa. O `feat`, por exemplo, é utilizado quando o desenvolvedor adiciona uma nova funcionalidade; Já o `refactor` é uma mudança no código, ou seja, uma refatoração. Eu costumo utilizar o padrão `[type] | [local]* | Description`, por exemplo: `[feat] | [Painel Admin] | Implements the X, Y and Z functionalities.`. A vantagem disso é a organização, fica muito mais fácil quando, por ventura, você utilizar o `git log`.

Comment: Links úteis: [Que tal começar a usar commits semânticos?](https://cubos.io/blog/que-tal-comecar-a-usar-commits-semanticos/) **/** [Semantic Commit Messages](https://seesparkbox.com/foundry/semantic_commit_messages) **e** [Commit Message Guidelines](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#-commit-message-guidelines)

Comment: Obrigado, Valdeir. Era exatamente isso que queria saber. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os commits semânticos da forma que você descreveu foram [propostos em um documento de convenções do AngularJS](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QrDFcIiPjSLDn3EL15IJygNPiHORgU1_OOAqWjiDU5Y/edit). Foram documentados e amplamente utilizados pelo [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/dev/git-commit-msg.html), um projeto *open source* de testes para JavaScript. Hoje, muitos projetos mantidos pela comunidade o utiliza, adaptando-se aos seus usos.

As *guidelines* recomendam o uso de tais convenções na mensagem de *commit* por:

1. Geração automática do *changelog*
2. Navegação facilitada no histórico do Git

O padrão de mensagem do *commit* semântico proposto é:

```
<tipo>(<escopo>): <assunto>

<corpo>

<rodapé>
```

Sendo `<tipo>` dos seguintes valores:

1. `feat`: quando se trata de uma nova funcionalidade (do inglês, *feature*)
2. `fix`: quando se trata de uma correção de *bug*
3. `docs`: quando se faz uma alteração na documentação
4. `style`: quando se trata de formatação de código
5. `refactor`: quando se trata de refatoração de código em produção
6. `test`: quando se adiciona ou refatora testes, sem impacto em código em produção
7. `chore`: quando se adiciona ou edita *tasks* do Grunt, ou Webpack, também sem impacto em produção

O `<escopo>` é opcional, principalmente se a alteração for global, mas bons exemplos seriam `init`, `runner`, `watcher`, `config`, `web-server`, `proxy`, etc.

Para o `<corpo>` da mensagem de *commit* recomenda-se:

1. Use a forma imperativa no presente dos verbos. Prefira "change" à "changed" ou "changes"
2. Inclua os motivos das mudanças no código em comparação ao comportamento anterior

O `<rodapé>` pode ser dedicado para notas e avisos importantes, como se existem mudanças radicais no código que caibam uma nota. Por exemplo:

```
MUDANÇA RADICAL:
A opção `port-runner` da linha de comando mudou para `runner-port`, para que permaneça consistente com a sintaxe do arquivo de configuração.
Para migrar seu projeto, mude todos os comandos, onde você usa `--port-runner`, para `--runner-port`.
```

Também pode ser utilizado para integrações, como fechar *issues* no GitHub utilizando a mensagem de commit.

```
Closes #123, #456, #789
```

Por ser uma iniciativa open source, essas *guidelines* são mantidas pela comunidade e opinadas em artigos. Um dos mais influentes é o [Semantic Commit Messages, do Sparkbox](https://seesparkbox.com/foundry/semantic_commit_messages).

> See how a minor change to your commit message style can make you a better programmer. I use a rigid commit message format, and it makes me a better programmer. You'll never again be tempted to include a bug fix and a feature in the same commit. My `git log` is now an easy-to-skim changelog.

Um exemplo de mensagem de *commit* seguindo esse padrão:

> ```
> fix($compilação): testes unitários no IE9
>
> Versões mais antigas do IE serializam HTML com tudo maiúsculo, mas o IE9 não.
> Seria melhor esperar um *case insensitive*, mas o Jasmine não aceita expressões regulares.
>
> Closes #392
> MUDANÇA RADICAL: quanto ao foo.bar, foo.baz deve ser utilizado ao invés disso.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

## Uso em Node.js

Só acrescentando a resposta do Vinicius, para quem tem interesse em seguir as *commit* padronizadas usando Node.js, existe um pacote no NPM chamado [*git-commit-msg-linter*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-commit-msg-linter) . Este pacote faz o ***linter*** das mensagens para mantê-las no [*Angular Commit Message Guidelines*](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#-commit-message-format). Vou mostrar também como personalizar as configurações das funcionalidades do pacote para permitir determinados tipos, adicionar novos tipos, mensagens de descrição de tipos e configurar tamanho máximo das mensagens de *commit*.

#### Como usar git-commit-msg-linter

Faça a instalação do pacote:

```
npm install git-commit-msg-linter --save-dev
```

Nenhuma configuração extra é necessária, basta que o *git repository* já esteja inicializado na pasta do projeto.

O pacote informa o formato de mensagem de *commit* a ser seguida:

<sup>Tradução adaptada</sup>

```
<type>(<scope>): <short summary>
  │       │             │
  │       │             └─⫸ Summary.
  │       │
  │       └─⫸ Commit Scope.
  |                          
  │
  └─⫸ Commit Type.: feat|fix|docs|style|refactor|test|chore|perf|ci|build|temp
```

- `Summary`:  Resumo no tempo presente. **Sem letras maiúsculas**. **Sem ponto final no final**.
- `Commit Scope`: Opcional, pode ser qualquer coisa especificando o escopo da alteração de confirmação.
  Por exemplo `$ location | $ browser | $ compile | $ rootScope | ngHref | ngClick | ngView`, etc.
  No desenvolvimento de aplicativos, o escopo pode ser uma página, um módulo ou um componente.
- `Commit Type`: São os tipos que o Vinicius mencionou, `feat | fix | docs | style | refactor | test | chore | perf | ci | build | temp`.

**Obs**: Os campos `type` e `short summary` são obrigatórios.

Temos uns exemplos:

- **Ruim**: O pacote lança um erro e **não faz o *commit* da mensagem**.

```bsh
$ git commit -m "Correct spelling of CHANGELOG."
```

O commit no formato acima não será válido e o pacote lançará um erro:

```
************* Invalid Git Commit Message **************
  commit message: adding git
  correct format: <type>[scope]: <subject>
  example: docs: update README to add developer tips

  type:
    feat     A new feature.
    fix      A bug fix.
    docs     Documentation only changes.
    style    Changes that do not affect the meaning of the code (white-space, formatting, missing semi-colons, etc).
    refactor A code change that neither fixes a bug nor adds a feature.
    test     Adding missing tests or correcting existing ones.
    chore    Changes to the build process or auxiliary tools and libraries such as documentation generation.
    perf     A code change that improves performance.
    ci       Changes to your CI configuration files and scripts.
    build    Changes that affect the build system or external dependencies (example scopes: gulp, broccoli, npm).
    temp     Temporary commit that won't be included in your CHANGELOG.

  scope:
    Optional, can be anything specifying the scope of the commit change.
    For example $location, $browser, $compile, $rootScope, ngHref, ngClick, ngView, etc.
    In App Development, scope can be a page, a module or a component.

  subject:
    Brief summary of the change in present tense. Not capitalized. No period at the end.
```

Repare que a mensagem tem ponto final (`.`) e começa com letra maiúscula (`C`).

- **Bons**: Os casos abaixam são aceitos.

```bsh
$ git commit -m "docs: correct spelling of CHANGELOG"
```

```bsh
$ git commit -m "docs(CHANGELOG): correct spelling"
```

O pacote possui configurações padrões como os tipos aceitos e tamanho máximo da mensagem de *commit* (por padrão, o máximo é `100`), mas isso pode ser facilmente personalizado de acordo com a necessidade do desenvolvedor. Basta criar um arquivo
`commitlinterrc.json` e definir as regras a serem usadas pelo pacote.

Exemplo:

```js
{
  "types": {
    "feat": "Nova funcionalidade do projeto",
    "build": "Nova build do projeto",
    "docs": "Nova documentacao do projeto",
    "testando": "Novo tipo pode ser usado",
    "temp": false,
    "chore": false
  },
  "max-len": 120,
  "debug": true
}
```

- Em `"types"`, definimos os tipos que serão aceitos no escopo `type` das mensagens.
- Em `"feat"`, por exemplo, alterei e coloquei uma descrição deste tipo que irá servir de consulta caso alguém faça um *commit* errado. Descrição:

  > <sup>nova funcionalidade do projeto</sup>
- Em `"temp"` e `"chore"` iguais a `false`, eu defino que esses tipos não podem ser usados nos *commits*.
- Em `"testando"` eu definir um novo tipo que pode ser usado no `type` das mensagens, e ainda coloco uma descrição deste tipo.
- `"max-len"` eu defino o novo tamanha máximo para as mensagens.

Agora, toda vez que eu escrever um *commit* em formato não aceito, teremos o seguinte erro no terminal:

```bsh
$ git c "chore: adding gitignore file"
```

<sup>Repare que `chore` não é aceito.</sup>

Saída:

```
[DEBUG] config: {
  types: {
    feat: 'Nova funcionalidade do projeto',
    build: 'Nova build do projeto',
    docs: 'Nova documentacao do projeto',
    testando: 'Novo tipo pode ser usado ',
    temp: false,
    chore: false
  },
  'max-len': 120,
  debug: true
} 
[DEBUG] commit message: |chore: adding gitignore file| 
[DEBUG] type: chore, scope: undefined, subject: adding gitignore file 

  ************* Invalid Git Commit Message **************
  commit message: chore: adding gitignore file
  correct format: <type>[scope]: <subject>
  example: docs: update README to add developer tips

  type:
    feat     Nova funcionalidade do projeto
    fix      A bug fix.
    docs     Nova documentacao do projeto
    style    Changes that do not affect the meaning of the code (white-space, formatting, missing semi-colons, etc).
    refactor A code change that neither fixes a bug nor adds a feature.
    test     Adding missing tests or correcting existing ones.
    perf     A code change that improves performance.
    ci       Changes to your CI configuration files and scripts.
    build    Nova build do projeto
    testando Novo tipo pode ser usado 

  scope:
    Optional, can be anything specifying the scope of the commit change.
    For example $location, $browser, $compile, $rootScope, ngHref, ngClick, ngView, etc.
    In App Development, scope can be a page, a module or a component.

  subject:
    Brief summary of the change in present tense. Not capitalized. No period at the end.
```

Repare que o `"debug": true` nos mostra o conteúdo do `.json` de configuração, além de informações adicionais prefixadas com `[DEBUG]`.

No `type`, temos os tipos e as descrições que personalizamos, além das que vem por padrão.

Para maiores informações de personalização das mensagens, consulte o link do NPM.

Espero que esta resposta seja de interesse pra alguém. Eu particulamente gosto e uso este pacote pelo fato de podermos personalizar tipos, descrições, tamanho de mensagens de *commit* o que o torna o *git* bem mais amigável, ainda mais para novatos que começam a usá-lo e para equipes que desejam criar padrões próprios em seus projetos.

:)